# signalR Disconnect in client browser after a while

Tags: javascript, c#, typescript, asp.net-core, signalr

I am using SignalR in asp.net core and it work correctly in visual studio but when i publish it to iis an when connect to server after a while signalR disconnect and browser show blow errors:

> [2019-09-24T18:46:05.446Z] Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Error occurred'.
>
> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING
>
> signalr.js:2678 [2019-09-24T18:46:05.711Z] Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Error occurred'.
>
> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING
>
> signalr.js:2678 [2019-09-24T18:46:05.713Z] Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Error occurred'.
>
> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

Comment: `connect to server after a while signalR disconnect and browser show blow errors` I’d like to know 1)How long can the established connection last? 2)whether the client can communicate with Hub server after you establish connection to hub, and whether client can connect to hub again if you refresh the page after it is disconnected to Hub server.

Comment: tanks
1- if server not communicate for about 20 second

Comment: 2- yes when refresh page it work again

Comment: when user browser inside the server and localhost it work correctly

Comment: Please check if you set [SignalR configurations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=dotnet#configure-server-options) and changed **ClientTimeoutInterval** and **KeepAliveInterval** etc.

Comment: `when user browser inside the server and localhost it work correctly` Please check if it uses same transport when user connect to hub from a client computer and from the server browser.

Answer (score 0):

Normally signalr have connection time out so you need to let signalr know you want to have long polling connection by setting this in your code

```
connection.start({ transport: 'longPolling' });
```

Comment: i test it and test KeepAliveInterval and HandshakeTimeout but not work